# Check $1 with sed to conditionally replace last occurrence of a word in a path string

Tags: bash, sed

I have a variable that contains a complete path name. I am trying to conditionally replace the last occurrence of a word in the path. Example script to show what I am trying

```
#!/bin/sh

testvar="/home/downloads/user/downloads"

if [ "$1" = "alternate" ]; then
  newtestvar=$(echo $testvar | sed -e 's/\(.*\)downloads$/\1alternate_downloads/g')
else
  newtestvar=$(echo $testvar | sed -e 's/\(.*\)downloads$/\1new_downloads/g')
fi

echo "testvar:" $testvar
echo "newtestvar:" $newtestvar
```

**Run #1**

```
$ ./foofile
testvar: /home/downloads/user/downloads
newtestvar: /home/downloads/user/new_downloads
```

**Run #2**

```
$ ./foofile alternate
testvar: /home/downloads/user/downloads
newtestvar: /home/downloads/user/alternate_downloads
```

I do get the intended result, but I am looking for a way to avoid the if/else and rather achieve the result by checking the $1 in context of sed.

## Edit-1

I replaced the `if/else` block with following shorthand. but it looks really clumsy and difficult to read.

```
newtestvar=$([[ $1 = "alternate" ]] && echo $testvar | sed -e 's/\(.*\)downloads$/\1alternate_downloads/g' || echo $testvar | sed -e 's/\(.*\)downloads$/\1new_downloads/g')
```

Comment: instead of `sed`, use `$(dirname "$testvar")"/alternate_downloads"` and `$(dirname "$testvar")"/new_downloads"` ... there is nothing wrong in using if-else for clarity

Comment: Wondering why you tagged question as `bash` when using `#!/bin/sh`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can probably not be done with sed, because sed has no way to test the value of a variable and then conditionally branch the execution.

However, it can be done with AWK:

```
#!/bin/sh

testvar="/home/downloads/user/downloads"

newtestvar=$(awk -v arg="$1" '{
    replacement = arg == "alternate" ? "alternate_downloads" : "new_downloads";
    sub("downloads$", replacement);
    print $0;
  }
' <<<"$testvar")

echo "testvar:" $testvar
echo "newtestvar:" $newtestvar
```

Comment: I see even substring such as `alt` matches unless I do the following in the **awk` program block `    replacement = alternate == "alternate" ? "alternate_downloads" : "new_downloads";**

Comment: Yes, this was by design. With my solution *any* argument, except the empty string, results in `alternate_downloads`, and *only* the empty string results in `new_downloads`. If *only* the exact string "alternate" should result in `alternate_downloads`, and *any* other argument (including the empty string) in `new_downloads`, then your solution is correct.

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect your proposed behaviour.

Comment: This is not really avoiding any `if/else` condition. `ternary operator` of awk is pretty much same as what OP posted in `EDIT` section of question.

Comment: @anubhava yes, there is still a condition, but I think what the OP actually wanted is to move this condition inside the program used for parsing the strings. This is not possible with sed, but it's possible with AWK. Your solution is very good too, but in fact also `${1:-new}` is nothing else than an if/else conditions, just in an even shorter form than a ternary operator.

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid `sed` and handle this in bash itself:

```
#!/bin/bash

testvar="/home/downloads/user/downloads"

# default s to "new"
s="${1:-new}"

# replace only last value of downloads
newtestvar="${testvar/%downloads/${s}_downloads}"

# examine both variables
declare -p testvar newtestvar
```

Now call it as:

```
./foofile
declare -- testvar="/home/downloads/user/downloads"
declare -- newtestvar="/home/downloads/user/new_downloads"

./foofile alternate
declare -- testvar="/home/downloads/user/downloads"
declare -- newtestvar="/home/downloads/user/alternate_downloads"
```